# In the controller, how can I manipulate object properties shown in a ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS, I have created a ng-repeat that shows object properties. I'd like to take `root.TooltipText` and be able to access it in the controller.

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div id="root">
    <div ng-repeat="root in rootresults">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showpagetwo(root.Title, root.ID)" ng-if="root.Location == null">{{root.Title}}
        <span class="tooltiptextsmall tooltip-rightsmall" ng-if="root.TooltipSize =='Small'">{{root.TooltipText}}</span>
        <span class="tooltiptextnormal tooltip-rightnormal" ng-if="root.TooltipSize =='Normal'">{{root.TooltipText}}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('wizardApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $scope.getRootList();
  });

  $scope.prepContext = function(url,listname,query){
    var path = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query;
    return path;
  }

  $scope.getRootList = function() {
    rootList = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: this.prepContext(siteOrigin+"/divisions/testing","SupportList","?$orderBy=Title&$filter=RootItem eq 'Yes'"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      //$("#articleSection").fadeIn(2000);
      console.log(data.data.d.results);
      $scope.rootresults = data.data.d.results;
    });
  };
});
```

Logging `data.data.d.results` logs:

```
{
  "0":  {
    "Title": "Test1",
    "TooltipText": "Test1",
    "TooltipSize": "Small"
    },
  "1":  {
    "Title": "Test2",
    "TooltipText": "Test2",
    "TooltipSize": "Small"
    },
  ...
}
```

How can I access object properties in the controller?

Comment: When do you want to access?

Comment: `$(document).ready` = big no no in an Angular application. Use jQuery, OR use Angular, but don't use both at the same time.

Comment: Call `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.rootresults = data.data.d.results;`

Comment: you don't have a TooltipSize attribute on your results. So none of them are showing because your ng-if statements don't validate

Comment: Did @Hazaart just cleanup the `data.data.d.results` for editing or  @cfoster5 was missing those quotes. Because missing those quotes would cause this malfunction.

Comment: @bhantol I was missing the quotes in the post.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the results it will work fine if your `console.log(data.data.d.results);` gets the expected data.

But you have to also change

> `ng-if="root.Location == null"`

to

> `ng-if="!root.Location"`

and the reason being that the root.Location is coming as `undefined` which is not same as `null`.